# Jenkins pipeline configure the options via code

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I use declarative Jenkins pipeline and each stage has options definition where I want to define the timeout and retry.

The values for those options come from configuration file.

I tried the below options, but it's not worked for me

1. I wrote method that do calculation of options

```
... 
options { myOptionCalculation() }
....
```

2. I tried to wrap it with the `script` block.

```
....
options { script { myOption() } }
...
```

In both cases I got the error that options is not supported my configuration

How I can control the option definition based on external configuration ?

Comment: Please show your complete code

Comment: `the stage-level options can only contain steps like retry, timeout, or timestamps, or Declarative options that are relevant to a stage, like skipDefaultCheckout.` Detail here: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#options

Comment: Thanks @young, this is exactly my question. I need to control the timeout via configuration file, so I try to find the way that I can define the `options` in stage somehow via groovy code